# When are finitely many steps necessary in a proof?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing

When describing a an algorithmic procedure in a proof, when is it necessary for this procedure to complete in a finite amount of time?

To give context and an example, a complex analysis professor of mine claimed that the proof of Cauchy-Goursat in Brown & Churchill's textbook was flawed, on the grounds that the procedure given to prove a lemma used in the proof would not take finitely many steps. Why is this a valid criticism?

For reference, here is a description of the proof strategy in Brown & Churchill. The context is that we have a region $R$ bounded by a Jordan curve, and an equally-spaced grid has been imposed upon $R$, so that $R$ is covered by a finite number of (square or partially-square) subregions. The goal is to prove that, for a function $f$ analytic of $R$, in each subregion there is a point $z_j$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$ and point $z$ in the same subregion, the following property holds: $$\left|\frac{f(z)-f(z_j)}{z-z_j}-f'(z_j)\right|<\epsilon.$$

> *To start the proof, we consider the possibility that in the covering constructed ..., there is some square or partial square in which no point $z_j$ [exists satisfying $P$]. If that subregion is a square, we construct four smaller squares by drawing line segments joining the midpoints of its opposite sides. If the region is a partial square, we treat the whole square in the same manner and then let the portions that lie outside of $R$ be discarded.*
>
> *If in any one of these smaller subregion, no point $z_j$ [exists satisfying $P$], we construct still smaller squares and partial squares, etc. When this is done to each of the original subregion that requires it, we find that **after a finite number of steps**, the region $R$ can be covered with a finite number of squares and partial squares such that the lemma is true.*

Comment: Without knowing the specific statement of the property $P$, this is a hard question to answer. I can imagine some situations for which this proof strategy would indeed work after finitely many steps, and other situations for which it would not.

Comment: @LeeMosher That's fair. I edited the question to include a description of the property.

Comment: I don't see any flaw in the proof, but you DO need an extra argument showing that the procedure necessarily ends after a finite number steps.  (Brown & Churchill give such an argument right after the claim.)

Comment: @Blackbird Why must the procedure end after finitely many steps?

Comment: Well, you should perhaps go back and read what Brown & Churchill are trying to achieve with this procedure.  The lemma they are trying to prove says that for every $\varepsilon>0$, it is possible to cover the region $R$ with a _finite_ number of rectangles such that blah blah.  Would they achieve this goal if the procedure didn't end after finitely many steps?